# ASP.NET MVC 4 updated jQuery but BundleConfig still looking for old version

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with the BundleConfig to reference my scripts and all was working fine.  However I've had a requirement to upgrade to jQuery 1.10 when moving to Bootstrap 3.  I've downloaded the jQuery 1.10 files and replaced the 1.7 files in my scripts directory.  However when I view a page on my site I get the following error message:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js' was not found or does not implement IController
```

and a corresponding

```
GET http://local.storetech.com/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js 404 (Not Found)
```

from the browser.

The inclusion of jQuery in the bundles is done using

```
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
```

My understanding of the version wildcard is that it uses a regular expression to match files in the specified directory with a version like file name.   The name of my current jQuery file is jquery-1.10.2.js in the scripts directory.  Why is MVC still trying to fetch the old jQuery file when I've updated to a newer one?

Comment: Did you try doing a search on your solution to see if there are any explicit references to the old file?

Comment: @asymptoticFault That's it thanks.  Another developer did something stupid.  Post this as an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: You are welcome!  Ah the joys of working on a team...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching the solution for explicit references to the old file.